# UITableViewCell with sections with min rows set does not get clear even after clearing data and reloadData call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView with sections and few rows for each section in a Popover where i have min row needs to be displayed even there is no data. Now after some action i want to clear the uitableview but it does seem to work still i could see few rows displayed.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return MAX([sectionArr count],1);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return MAX([dataArr[section] count], 5);
}

//with other delagates 

-(void) afterSomeAction
{
sectionArr = 0;
dataArr= 0;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Setting no of rows to zero clears the data but height of popover stays taller for bigger table or popover shrinks on calling viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad

Note : Not interested in setting size of tableview or using [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:..  withRowAnimation:..] as data populated are more dynamic.

Comment: sectionArr = 0;
dataArr= 0;
is this valid syntax ?

Comment: it is only an example to say it is NSArray

Comment: You don't have use 1 and 5 as a static. take int and set their value also zero when you clear data and you don't want to clear that row or section.

Comment: numbers are for minimum number of rows to displayed in popover window, i did not understand 'take int....'

Comment: Why are you taking the MAX() of the dataSource array and 5? And the sectionArray and 1?

Comment: in popover window i like to show min number of rows..